# Share on LinkedIn URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, linkedin-api

I need to share a certificate (which is actually a picture) on LinkedIn as a certificate. I'm using this link:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=

and then append the URL of the picture. I tried 3 different approach, but none worked. The file is on an s3 bucket.

- I tried to generate a presigned url, and append that url after the link: the presigned url works fine (I tried to past it on incognito mode and I can see the picture), but LinkedIn says there is an error;
- I tried to make this file public, accessible to everyone with the link, and append the URL to the link.. same error result;
- I tried to append there an API of my backend (in dotnet) which is public and not protected with bearer token, which returns a FileStreamResults, but still getting the same error.

This is the error I'm getting on all these attempts:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8basr.png)

It's quite generic, not helping at all to understand the issue. What do you think am I doing wrong? How can make this work?

Comment: What does https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ say, when you try to debug your URL using that?

Comment: We cannot display a preview for this URL.

Ingestion feedback
Error We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.

Comment: Maybe they don't allow sharing of plain image URLs in general - and expect the URL to an HTML document that contains OG meta tags ...? (If so, you could create one, that has your image specified as the thumbnail.)